# Infinite Scrolling not working for ngInfiniteScrol

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll

I am new to AngularJS and trying to implement infinite scrolling using https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll.

However my code gives me the following error on console on the browser. What is confusing me is that it is pointing to the code in the library I am using and not my code. IS this a bug from my side or in the   some linking error?

Has anyone else used this and faced a similar issue. I cannot really post my source code since its quite big at this point and I am using the infinite-scroll when I am using the ng-repeat directive to list results. Thank you

> ng-infinite-scroll.js:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

Here is my `app.js`

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name angularSocketNodeApp
 * @description
 * # angularSocketNodeApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
```

// Added 'ngInfiniteScroll' below

```
angular.module('angularSocketNodeApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'btford.socket-io',
        'angular-md5',
        'ngInfiniteScroll'
    ])

.factory('theSocket', function(socketFactory) {
    var myIoSocket = io.connect('/');

    var theSocket = socketFactory({
        ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });

    return theSocket;
})


.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl'
        })
        .when('/search', {
            templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchCtrl'
        })
        .when('/search/:query', {
            templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
            controller: 'SearchCtrl'
        })
        .when('/teacher', {
            templateUrl: 'views/teacher.html',
            controller: 'TeacherCtrl'
        })
        .when('/class/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'views/class.html',
            controller: 'ClassCtrl'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
            controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
        })
        .when('/login/teacher', {
            templateUrl: 'views/loginteacher.html',
            controller: 'LogInTeacherCtrl'
        })
        .when('/login/student', {
            templateUrl: 'views/loginstudent.html',
            controller: 'LogInStudentCtrl'
        })
        .when('/u/:username/:classname', {
            templateUrl: 'views/class.html',
            controller: 'ClassCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/search'
        });
});
```

Comment: Can please post your app.js